# string formatting appears differently on different environment

Tags: python, string, slack-api

I'm trying to send text from python to slack by using slackbotAPI.
I processed text like this: (looks neat)
[image]

I formatted string by this code line:
[image]

But after sending this text by slackbot API, text appeared on slack like this:
[image]

I guess the width of each character(include space)is different on slack, but not on python prompt.
How can I see the text neatly on slack like on python?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't know, but maybe it's not an issue with the width of characters and the different fonts you showed in this two pictures (it would be better to give code samples by copypasting instead of pics, btw) it might be related to how slack or the API you're using deals with tabulation `\t`.

But just in case I'm wrong at it's just a matter of fonts you could try to change them with this trick I just found out [How to change your font in Slack](https://www.theverge.com/21432669/slack-font-change-how-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve what you're looking for isn't with text characters like tabs etc, but to use [fields inside a section block](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/blocks#section_fields).

That will make sure that regardless of interface, they're arranged correctly.

[Here's an example](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/T9TK3CUKW#%7B%22blocks%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22text%22:%7B%22text%22:%22A%20message%20*with%20some%20bold%20text*%20and%20_some%20italicized%20text_.%22,%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22%7D,%22fields%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22*Priority*%22%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22*Type*%22%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22plain_text%22,%22text%22:%22High%22%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22plain_text%22,%22text%22:%22String%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D)

[image: Screenshot of a slack message with fields]